# JSDoc: элемент массива

Tags: javascript, документация, jsdoc

Приведу пример исходной структуры:

```
var arr = {
    sub: [
        { idx: 0, name: '...' },
        { idx: 1, name: '...' },
        { idx: 2, name: '...' }
    ]
};
```

Функция:

```
/**
 * @param {String}
 * @return {arr.sub.?} 
 */ 
arr.isDefined = function(opt) {
    return this.sub.find(function(item) {
        return item.name === opt;
    });
};
```

Есть ли способ указать тип возвращемого элемента, используя имя\тип объекта, в котором находится массив с вышеупомянутым элементом? 
P.S. Извините за формулировку :)

Comment: Функция `typeof(x)` определяет тип данных аргумента.

Comment: @Дмытрык, и ее можно использовать в JSDoc?

Comment: Не знаю. Изначально не понял Ваш вопрос, сорри.

Comment: @Дмытрык, ничего страшного, бывает :)